# How do I get confirmation that the piece of code completed its execution in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am using array-query `npm` plugin and I have large array records from which I choose the records with matching conditions.

The code for it is as below.

## code

```
var result = query(col).within(list).on(postDetails);
```

It will select records based on provided condition from `postDetails` array

Now how I can confirm that all matching records are selected before any other code executes as `postDetails` array is large and can take few time to complete.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read [ask] and [mcve]. Make sure to add your efforts.

Comment: Do you have some reason to think that any of the functions you are using are asynchronous?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to what I see in the [README](https://github.com/jacwright/array-query), this library is synchronous, so you get the confirmation by the program exiting or stepping to the next line.

Comment: I agree. The documentation says it only executes the whole chain as soon as on(data) is called:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/array-query#querying